# What does CNAME '@ (None)' entry resolve to?

Tags: cname

Network solutions has an entry '@ (None)' in the CNAME record.

What domain resolution processes the '@ (None)' entry?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests to the root-level domain, i.e. yahoo.com instead of www.yahoo.com.